# Capturar o TraceSql de consulta em LINQ c#

Tags: c#, linq

Tenho uma consulta em *LINQ* e preciso capturar o sql gerado, mas não tive sucesso. A conversão para *ObjectQuery* que encontrei não funciona. O que falta?

```
var sqlConsulta = (from a in Sessao.Query<RequisitorioNaoLevantado>()
                  where (a.Codvara == codigoVara) &&
                      (string.IsNullOrEmpty(numeroProcesso) || 
                       a.AcaoOriginaria.Equals(numeroProcesso)) 
                 select a);

var sqlGerado = (ObjectQuery)sqlConsulta;
var commandSql = sqlGerado.ToTraceString();
```

Para sqlConsulta.ToString(), temos:

> NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[Modelo.Entidades.Esparta.RequisitorioNaoLevantado]

A linha (ObjectQuery)sqlConsulta, gera a exceção:

> "Cannont cast 'sqlConsulta' (which has an actual type of 'NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[Modelo.Entidades.Esparta.RequisitorioNaoLevantado]' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery"

Comment: Isso é o quê?  Entity Framework?

Comment: Os recursos utilizado são: NHibernat + FluentNHibernate + Linq;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem um referencia para o Fluent NHibernate no stackoverflow em inglês [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134565/how-to-configure-fluent-nhibernate-to-output-queries-to-trace-or-debug-instead-o/5437641#5437641)

Escreva um interceptor:

```
using NHibernate;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class SqlStatementInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
{
    public override NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString OnPrepareStatement(NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString sql)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(sql.ToString());
        return sql;
    }
}
```

No seu gerente de conexão, conecte seu Interceptor assim:

```
protected virtual void Configure(FluentConfiguration config)
{
    config.ExposeConfiguration(x =>
                                   {
                                       x.SetInterceptor(new SqlStatementInterceptor());
                                   });
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Ayrton, parabéns pela objetividade e clareza da resposta!